# how to format out with printf in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to print at a specific position on screen, it worked and is formatted well when I hardcode `yaxis` value but it does not work when I pass `$yaxis` as parameter to `printf`. Instead, it prints only first word as shown. Any idea why? and how can I fix this?

```
#Working:
my $var= "Hello, this is test output";

printf ("%20s\n", $var);

 #output:           
 #Hello, this is test output 

#not working:     
my $yaxis= "20";
printf ("%${yaxis}s\n", $var);

#Output:
#                       Hello
```

Comment: `%20s` means a minimum width of 20. As `length $var >= 20`, it won't have any effect. I copy-pasted your code and can't reproduce only the first word printing.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unable to reproduce your problems.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $var= "Hello, this is test output";
printf ("%20s\n", $var);

my $yaxis= 20;
printf ("%${yaxis}s\n", $var);
```

outputs:

```
Hello, this is test output
Hello, this is test output
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you are wanting to do is use a variable to indent string output try this minor modification:

```
my $var= "Hello, this is test output";
printf ("%20s\n", $var);
my $indent = 20;
printf ("%${indent}s%s\n", "", $var);
```

It will output:

```
Hello, this is test output
                    Hello, this is test output
```